# unit testing factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to unit test angular factory method which is performing some API call.

```
fileUploadFcty.getImage(imageParams)
           .then(function (image) {
                  console.log(image)
               }
           });
```

when I unit tests this it is not showing anything inside the console. I have tried to mock it and returning the response data.

Comment: Is that an async factory method? What is it actually doing? We don't need the real code but at least details for the API expectations here.

Comment: it is returning a $promise

Comment: But what does the promise resolution itself return? Is it an image? Something else? Does it fail? *Can* it fail?

Comment: it is returning a string for eg:- asdasd1asd2

Comment: Show the relevant part of your unit test, please.